# How to change Format of a Cell to Text using VBA, Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@" doesn't work for me

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am parsing a string and the answer is a three digit number format.  I have tried a few ways and I can get the XXX format but when the answer is preceded by zeros, Excel always displays as 1 and not 001.
If I use a direct trim function in Excel, it displays properly but I need in macro format as I don't want formulas in my spreadsheet.
=RIGHT(TRIM(L4),3) --this displays properly as 001, the string I want parsed is in L4

I have tried the  `Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"`   --- but still get the 1, not 001.

I have tried two ways so far, to use a variable and directly compute.  The variable(SerialNum) has stored value of "001":
`wsCopyTo.Cells(j - 1, i).Value = SerialNum`  --- result is displayed as 1
and tried to directly compute as in the formula in the spreadsheet from column "F" in another spreadsheet:
`wsCopyTo.Cells(j - 1, 1).Value = Right(wsCopyFrom.Cells(j, "F"), 3)`  --- result is displayed as 1

How can I get the data to transfer properly from a STRING in VB to display in the spreadsheet correctly.  001 and not just 1

I would really appreciate some help,
Thank you in advance,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

The number format you are looking for is `.NumberFormat = "000"`.